# Aligning a checkbox and the text next to it

Tags: css, html

I have a checkbox and the message next to the checkbox is ong. When the message stacks up, I want the 2nd line of the message to stack with the first line. Right now, it aligns with the check box. Is there a way I can do that?

HTML

```
<label for="MailingList" class="MailingList">
<input type="checkbox" id="MailingList" name="MailingList">Messsage goes here. Messsage goes here. Messsage goes here. Messsage goes here. Messsage goes here. Messsage goes here. Messsage goes here. Messsage goes here   
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.MailingList,
{
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 6px;
font-family: "HelveticaNeueMedium", "HelveticaNeue-Medium", "Helvetica Neue Medium", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica";
font-size: 14px;
color: #666;
font-style: normal;
text-align: left;
line-height: 14.4pt;
letter-spacing: 0em;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vc8u1rfr/

Is there a way I can fix it? Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Corrected JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vc8u1rfr/4/

Comment: Your JSFiddle does not run.

Comment: Because of unclosed attributes in the various elements...

Comment: I've updated a fixed fiddle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set a padding to the left of the label, you push all the text (and the checkbox) a bit to the right. Now if you pull back the checkbox that same amount with a negative margin you end up with the desired effect

```css
label {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
   
input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
 </label>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following CSS:

```css
label {
  /* to allow for child elements to be positioned
     in relation to this container: */
  position: relative;
  /* to take the full width of the parent element: */
  display: block;
  /* creating an empty space of 50px: */
  padding-left: 50px;
}

label :first-child {
  /* taking the element out of the document flow,
     positioning it in the empty space created
     by the padding-left on the parent element: */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<label for="MailingList" class="MailingList">
    <input type="checkbox" id="MailingList" name="MailingList" />Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here</label>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vc8u1rfr/5/).

A more contemporary solution to the problem, though, is to use `display: flex;` or `display: grid;`:

```css
label {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

label.flex {
  display: flex;
}

label.grid {
  display: grid;
  /* by default elements are laid into
     a grid by row, but we want the element
     and text-content side-by-side, so we
     define the two columns: */
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
}

input {
/* If you opt to use CSS Grid, then this,
   used to provide a space between the 
   <input> and text can be removed, and
   the 'grid-gap' (or 'gap' in supporting
   browsers) can be used instead in the
   label's CSS: */
  margin-right: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<label for="MailingList2" class="MailingList flex">
    <input type="checkbox" id="MailingList" name="MailingList" />Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here</label>
<label for="MailingList2" class="MailingList grid">
    <input type="checkbox" id="MailingList" name="MailingList" />Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here Message goes here</label>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qzw93v1r/1/).